# Using groupBy to improve my Select (select count) query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, count, group-by

Let's say we have this and want to see all Tasks, that havent been done yet and an additional column showing how many open Tasks there are left for this customer.

**I have a table like this in my database:**

```
+------------+--------------------------+-------+
| CustomerID |           Task           | Done  |
+------------+--------------------------+-------+
|          1 | CleanRoom                | False |
|          1 | Cleandishes              | True  |
|          1 | WashClothes              | False |
|          2 | TakeDogsOut              | True  |
|          2 | PlayWithKids             | True  |
|          3 | HaveFunWithMrSamplesWife | True  |
|          3 | CleanMrSamplesCar        | False |
+------------+--------------------------+-------+
```

**I need this as returned table:**

```
+------------+-------------------+-------------+
| CustomerID |       Task        | DoneOverAll |
+------------+-------------------+-------------+
|          1 | CleanRoom         | 2           |
|          1 | WashClothes       | 2           |
|          3 | CleanMrSamplesCar | 1           |
+------------+-------------------+-------------+
```

**Perfect return table would be like this, but I can do that myself when I have the one above:**
About this a question; Doing this will probably be a String combination task. Should I do this on the Select statement, or would it be more advisable to do that in the final application on the client computer?

```
+------------+-------------------+-------------+
| CustomerID |       Task        | DoneOverAll |
+------------+-------------------+-------------+
|          1 | CleanRoom         | 1/3         |
|          1 | WashClothes       | 1/3         |
|          3 | CleanMrSamplesCar | 1/2         |
+------------+-------------------+-------------+
```

I know I could go like

```
SELECT 
  a.CustomerID, 
  a.Task, 
  (
     Select count(*) from myTable where 
     customerID = a.CustomerID and 
     done = False
   ) as DoneOverAll 
 FROM myTable as a
 WHERE Done = False
```

But I think that this is very ineffective, since it would execute a Select Count for each row in my table. Is there a way to achieve this with a `JOIN` using `groupBy` or something? I'm not into GroupBy commands yet.

---

Okay I should have tried first. Came up with the following;

```
Select count(*), CustomerID from myTable group by CustomerID
```

All I need to do now is to get this into a join.

---

Okay, got it. Sorry again for not trying first!

```
SELECT 
  a.CustomerID, 
  a.Task, 
  b.cnt
 FROM myTable as a
 LEFT JOIN (select count(*) AS cnt, CustomerID FROM myTable GROUP BY CustomerID) as b on a.CustomerID = B.CustomerID
 WHERE Done = False
```

---

Question left;
**Perfect return table would be like this, but I can do that myself when I have the one above:**
About this a question; Doing this will probably be a String combination task. Should I do this on the Select statement, or would it be more advisable to do that in the final application on the client computer?

```
+------------+-------------------+-------------+
| CustomerID |       Task        | DoneOverAll |
+------------+-------------------+-------------+
|          1 | CleanRoom         | 1/3         |
|          1 | WashClothes       | 1/3         |
|          3 | CleanMrSamplesCar | 1/2         |
+------------+-------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: You should use `SUM(CASE()) Group By CustomerID, Task` instead of the LEFT JOIN. I think that would be easier.

Comment: Wouldn't `Done = True`?

Comment: @WEI_DBA Do you have a SUM() sample for me? Guess I'm learning even more today! About the `done = true` : It actually doesnt matter. This is just a random table wrote down for the question. The used function is what I need to understand.

Comment: Sure. Posted as answer.

Comment: @WEI_DBA now I got what you mean by `Done = true`. Yeah, `DoneOverAll` should definitly be more like `OpenTasks` or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why `Done = False`, but this is your logic. :-)

Here's what I would do, without the `LEFT JOIN`.

```
    SELECT 
      a.CustomerID, 
      a.Task, 
      SUM(CASE WHEN a.Done = 'False' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DoneOverAll,
      SUM(Case WHEN a.Done = 'True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) NotDone
     FROM myTable as a 
     Group By a.CustomerID, a.Task
```

Comment: Can you explain me the use of SUM()? And also: Is the Group By needed for the SUM() ? Getting an error on my actualy query when using SUM without Group BY

Comment: The SUM() function is an aggregate function, meaning it will get the sum of all values within the parenthesis (). In this example, the `1` and `0` values based on the `Case` statement. So any column that is not in the SUM() function needs to be in the `Group By` clause. Google `SQL Server SUM() function` for more in-depth details.

Comment: I think I understand it now. Nice! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Do calculate separately .

```
     ;with tempfalse as(

              SELECT 
                  a.CustomerID, 
                  a.Task, 
                  count(*) as DoneOverAll 
             FROM myTable as a
             WHERE Done = False
             group by a.CustomerID,   a.Task
     )

    , temptrue (
           SELECT 
               a.CustomerID, 
               a.Task, 
               count(*) as total 
         FROM myTable as a
         group by a.CustomerID,  a.Task
     )

         SELECT 
           a.CustomerID, 
           a.Task, 
           cast(NULLIF(DoneOverAll,0) as varchar (10) ) + '/' +  cast(NULLIF(b.total,0) as varchar (10) )
             from temptrue as a left join tempfalse b 
           on  a.CustomerID =a.CustomerID and  
           a.Task = b.Task
```